# CSS background in four pieces

Tags: css

I have a problem with a background-image:

```
width: 1920px;
height: 1080px;
background-image: url("pictures/b1.jpg");
background-attachment: fixed;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
```

The picture is 1920X1080, I checked, but on my website it appears divided into four pieces [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRnFd.jpg) Why? please help

Comment: use `background-repeat:no-repeat`css property

Comment: can u please post ur code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these properties:

`background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;`

If that doesn't create the right appearance, try tweaking the `background-size` value. You could try `100% auto`, or `contain`, for starters. If you want the image to align to the top left instead of the center, use `background-position: 0 0;`.